# Api call on scroll event in blazor dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor webassembly app in which i have to implement infinite scroll
as well as pagination on scrolling.
I have to load 10 data at a time on page and make another api call when user scroll down to last

I am using SfListView for displaying data

Can anyone help me!

```
<SfListView Height="95%" CssClass="e-list-template listview-template" EnableVirtualization="true" DataSource="@ActivityFeedList" TValue="@FeedPostActivityModel">

                    <ListViewTemplates TValue="@FeedPostActivityModel">
                        <Template Context="data">
                            @{
                                <div class="test_block" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                                        <SectionPanel>
                                            
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col text-start">
                                                    <span class="small text-secondary">
                                                        @DisplayPostTime(data.ActivityFeedMetaData.PostDate)
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            
                                        </SectionPanel>
                                   
                                </div>
                            }
                        </Template>
                    </ListViewTemplates>
                    <ListViewFieldSettings TValue="@FeedPostActivityModel"></ListViewFieldSettings>
                </SfListView>
```

Comment: it looks like we only have this: https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/listview/loadmore

Comment: [Polite] - You need to provide more detail.  Where are you stuck other than how do I implement a `SfListView` which should be covered in Synfusion's documentation.